# Ubuntu crashed once shortly after partitioning during install. My second attempt was successful, but I have some concerns

Tags: installation, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

Is there something I should check, or a procedure I should perform, to make sure that nothing is wrong with my hard-drive or partitions?

And I noticed that I wasn't asked to define a partition size the second attempt at installation. I assumed that the Ubuntu installation picked up from where it left off (shortly after defining the partition size) - is this correct?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your system boots, the operating systems residing in each partition will likely automatically check the hard disk for corruption. The partition table is clean, and if you really want to check everything out, you can run `fsck` to check for filesystem troubles.

Assuming you only wanted 4 GB for Ubuntu, it all looks alright. That's a small allocation, though, and you might run into trouble installing the packages you want.